# iOS Local Notification Action in Background

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, uilocalnotification, stripe-payments

I'm building an application that when a user receives a local notification it charges their credit card via stripe and parse, there is more to it then that but thats the start. When the notification is received inside the app everything works fine but when the notification is received outside the app the action is not complete.

https://github.com/jackintosh7/Wake

I would the action to be complete outside the app and also a view to be brought up when the user clicks on the notification.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    if ([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]){
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

    if (StripePublishableKey) {
        [Stripe setDefaultPublishableKey:StripePublishableKey];
    }
    if (ParseApplicationId && ParseClientKey) {
        [Parse setApplicationId:ParseApplicationId
                      clientKey:ParseClientKey];
    }

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"Customer Created"]) {
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Customer Created"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Tutorial"];
        self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
    }


    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"1");




    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{




    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{



    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{




    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    [self saveContext];
}

- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AlarmModel" withExtension:@"mom"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"AlarmModel.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

         Typical reasons for an error here include:
         * The persistent store is not accessible;
         * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
         Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.


         If the persistent store is not accessible, there is typically something wrong with the file path. Often, a file URL is pointing into the application's resources directory instead of a writeable directory.

         If you encounter schema incompatibility errors during development, you can reduce their frequency by:
         * Simply deleting the existing store:
         [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil]

         * Performing automatic lightweight migration by passing the following dictionary as the options parameter:
         @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES}

         Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wake" message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];

    });

    NSString *customerId = @"cus_4ot6ggKUOp6bHg";
    NSNumber *amountInCents = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 1000];
    [self chargeCustomer:customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:^(id object, NSError *error) { }];
    NSLog(@"11");
}

-(void)chargeCustomer:(NSString *)customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{
    NSLog(@"22");

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeCustomer"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"amount":amountInCents,
                                        @"customerId":customerId
                                        }
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe charge information, you can use this as is or create, an instance of your own charge class.
                                    handler(object,error);

                                }];

}



#pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}

@end
```

**Action:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wake" message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];

    NSString *customerId = @"cus_4ot6ggKUOp6bHg";
    NSNumber *amountInCents = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 1000];
    [AppDelegate chargeCustomer:customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:^(id object, NSError *error) { }];
    NSLog(@"11");
}

+(void)chargeCustomer:(NSString *)customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{
    NSLog(@"22");

    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeCustomer"
                       withParameters:@{
                                        @"amount":amountInCents,
                                        @"customerId":customerId
                                        }
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                    //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe charge information, you can use this as is or create, an instance of your own charge class.
                                    handler(object,error);

                                }];

}
```

**Result of nslogs you added:**
See the charge information:(null)
Error:invalid_request_error: No such customer: cus_4ot6ggKUOp6bHg (Code: 141, Version: 1.4.1)
The last one I understand what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when your app is running application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is calling, but if your App is not running, the information about the local notifications is added to launchOptions dict;

In your AppDelegate, in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions add this code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Keep al exist code in your app...and at the END of this methods

UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotification) {
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:localNotification];
}

return YES;
}
```

It´s good thing to force the UIAlert in the main thread,:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
               ^{
                   UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wake" message:notification.alertBody delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                   [alertView show];
});
```

New Proposal:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wake" message:notification.alertBody delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertView show];
NSString *customerId = @"cus_4ot6ggKUOp6bHg";
NSNumber *amountInCents = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: 1000];
[self chargeCustomer:customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:^(id object, NSError *error) { }];

});
```

}

And :

```
-(void)chargeCustomer:(NSString *)customerId amount:(NSNumber *)amountInCents completion:(PFIdResultBlock)handler
{


[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"chargeCustomer"
                   withParameters:@{
                                    @"amount":amountInCents,
                                    @"customerId":customerId
                                    }
                            block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                //Object is an NSDictionary that contains the stripe charge information, you can use this as is or create, an instance of your own charge class.
                                handler(object,error);
                                NSLog(@"See the error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                NSLog(@"See the charge information:%@",[object description]);

                            }];

}
```

Comment: Okay I added the code above but I'm still having the same issue the action is not being completed when not in the app. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jack But show the code you added. Obviously nothing is going to be "completed" unless _you_ complete it. Prove that you are doing so.

Comment: You can be sure than if your app is wake up from a Local Notifications the methods will be call. (Use some NSLog to see what happens).

Comment: @OnikIV Ok I'm officially lost I don't know what to do, I have edited the question with my full appdelegate.m code. Hopefully this will help. I apologize for being a pain.

Comment: In you code, move: UILocalNotification *localNotification = [launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotification) {
    [self application:application didReceiveLocalNotification:localNotification];
} To the bottom of the methods.

Comment: Hi Jack, I haven´t be able fire your code ( I´m not update my Xcode, and there is some lib I don´t have). Today I wont have more time to this. But at first, It's really strange than it works fine when the app is running, and it have some problems when the notification wake up the App, because the code it´s the same, the only explanation could be than there is some class than start in View Controller or another than it´s no ready when the app started. You can try two things, one delay the methods, another look the error in the callback. I put the new code in this answer

Comment: Please tell me, what´s the log result to: NSLog(@"See the error:%@",[error localizedDescription]);
                                    NSLog(@"See the charge information:%@",[object description]);

Comment: @OnikIV Okay this seems to work somewhat, when the user clicks on the local notification the action is completed. But when the notification is received and the user doesn't interact with it the action is not being completed. Is there anyway that once the user receives the notification the action is completed even if they don't interact with it?

Comment: @Jack, if the user does not interact with the notifications, you don´t have any information about it in your app. Your App won't enter in any background or foreground mode. (Nothing happens). You can save in any way the notification you send (Core Data, Plist, user defaults...), and when the user open again the app, you can see what has been sent and the user don´t interact and make the work.
But if the user don´t touch your app doesn´t live.